# Barra de navegación superior

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy intentando hacer una barra de navegación superior para una web y la cosa es que no consigo que este completamente pegada arriba y entre las opciones hay huecos clicables que están vacíos y me gustaría quitarlos. Alguien puede darme alguna pista o explicarme un poco como hacerlo? He buscado en internet y no consigo hacerlo con la información que me dan.

He aquí el código:

```css
body{
  background:#3CF;
}
.contenedor {
  width: 95%;
  max-width:1200px;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-rigth:0px;
}

.contenedor p {
  margin-bottom:40px;
}

header nav {
  background:#3498db;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

header nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

header nav ul li a {
  padding:40px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  background:#2980b9;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class ="contenedor">
    <nav class = "menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a title="Home" href="YustaHome.html"> Home </li>
        <li><a title="Tattos" href="https://www.google.es/"> Tattos</li>
        <li><a title="Drawings" href=""> Drawings </li>
        <li><a title="About" href=""> About </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error mas grave que tenías era que no estabas cerrando ninguna etiqueta `<a>` dentro de tu menú de navegación, lo que generaba los huecos clicables a los que te referías.

Ahora, te recomiendo siempre usar el selector universal de css que es un asterisco (*) y resetear las márgenes internas y externas para todos los elementos ya que los navegadores utilizan márgenes predeterminadas para algunos tipos de elementos.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background:#3CF;
}
.contenedor {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

.contenedor p {
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

header nav {
    background:#3498db;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

header nav ul li a {
    padding:40px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
    background:#2980b9;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class ="contenedor">
        <nav class = "menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a title="Home" href="YustaHome.html"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a title="Tattos" href="https://www.google.es/"> Tattos </a></li>
                <li><a title="Drawings" href=""> Drawings </a></li>
                <li><a title="About" href=""> About </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Te me has adelantado por segundos! Cancelo mi respuesta pues viene a ser lo mismo.